# Dual boot OS recovery using Testdisk

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, partition-recovery, testdisk

I have a Dell Latitude with an internal storage drive of 500GB. I dual boot Windows and Kali OS. A few days ago, I messed up and wiped the drive using `diskpart` `clean` command and now I'm trying to recover the data and OSes.

I am using Testdisk from Fedora liveboot. When I initially analysed the disk, this was the state of the drive:

[image: initial drive analysis using testdisk]

The instructions were to pick which partitions to recover by changing their letters from from *D* to ***, *P*, *L*, or *E*.

The first thing I did not understand is that I was unable to change any of the partitions to *E* or *L* but I assumed it's because it would need to be further subdivided so I ignored it.

Since it looked like I could only select a maximum of 4 partitions to recover, I took a guess that the partition labeled **EFI system partition** could be the one with boot instructions so, I changed it to *** and the other 3 that are labeled **HPFS - NTFS**. I confirmed my choices and exited the tool (since it indicated that I need to restart for the changes to take effect).

Upon restarting, there was no bootable drive found again. I got back in using the stick and inspected the state of the drive and this is what I found:

[image: new state of the drive after testdisk recovery]

If I go on to select the `Quick search` option, it takes me again to a partition listing similar to the one in the first image.

Now I don't know how to proceed, should I randomly choose another set of partitions? If I do that, what happens to the current state of the drive? Does it re-write the data? Has the new partitions been really written to the disk? I need help on how to proceed to recover my operating systems.

**PS:** if all fails, I'd love to at least recover my Kali OS since it's the active one.

Comment: Looks to me like you need all the partitions. Why can't you choose more than 4? Try some [TestDisk alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/testdisk/?p=2).

Comment: When selecting the partitions you have to change the letters from D to P (L or E is not available as I mentioned) now, if you change more than 3 to P (Primary), you cannot continue. As to alternatives, I'm ready to try them when I'm sure that Testdisk hasn't written the changes to the drive (which is one of my questions).

Comment: The partitions table was changed by TestDisk, as in your answer. Seems like your disk is analyzed as MBR that can have only 4 primary partitions. Was it MBR or GPT before the `clean` command?

Comment: @John I could copy the contents since they are accessible using partitions but I'm not sure how I would put them back together, for instance, I don't know how Kali dispatched itself to multiple partitions; you can see there is a number of them that are labelled Linux.

Comment: @harrymc you are right! it was changed by TestDisk. I think it was MBR, is there a way to look it up?

Comment: Converting to GPT might destroy the previous partitions beyond recovery. Try perhaps some [TestDisk Alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/testdisk/).

Comment: Will Testdisk convert it to GPT? I've visited the link but they are many. Which one would you recommend next?

Comment: As @harrymc try using some alternative tool, for example show partition TAB in DMDE. Anyway, MBR type partitions => 4 partitions max, or 3 primary + 1 extended. In your case however probably GPT partition table.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen so it's safe? I was just worried that Testdisk has already written the new changes (in image two) to the drive.

Comment: I'm also curious as to why the question was downvoted? I have clearly stated the problem and the steps I've taken to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Harrymc, I tried alternative software and ended up using a dell recovery [image](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/osiso/win) to recover the partitions.